# What browsers currently implement support for the HTML5 MediaController?

Tags: api, html, cross-browser, media, browser-support

So my Google fu has failed me. Is there a know list of browsers (including beta versions) that support the [HTML5 MediaController object](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#synchronising-multiple-media-elements)?

Answer (score 2):

No browsers support MediaController.

Safari claims support, but it doesn't work well enough to actually use.

Chrome have removed default support and put it behind an experimental flag. Turns out, it was never properly implemented in Chrome in the first place: it didn't maintain synchronisation, it was simply play/pause/seek both media at the same time and hope for the best. (see https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/MVcoNSPs1UQ/LIF-fvu2lwoJ)

Answer (score 0):

I know that Safari can control the video object. But I'm not sure if it can use HTML5 MediaController.

See some example in : 
[Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

You can test support for MediaController using this simple but not perfect code:

```
function checkSupport() {
    if (!("MediaController" in window)) {
        return "unsupported";
    }
    var mc = new MediaController();
    if ("onended" in mc) {
        return "supported";
    } else {
        return "partially supported";
    }
}
```

Or open this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/achwedyk/Hk393/

I've tested various browsers and currently (April 2014) only Chrome 34 and Safari 7 partially support MediaController. However there is open bug for missing event handlers: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94891