# Is it possible to prefetch webpage audio and play it early, so it syncs with the video? Is there a javascript command for that?

Tags: javascript, html, web, audio, video

What I want to do is that there are some videos online that audio and video are out of sync. I wonder if it is possible to preload the audio and pre-play the audio so it syncs with video. Is there a javascript command for that?

I have seen preload attribute in HTML, but it only loads the audio and video. Is it possible to play the audio before the video starts?

From what I am understanding, I feel like audio is attached to the video. By that I mean you cannot get the audio to play ahead of the video, only postpone it. I wonder if there is a way to play the audio like 1 second ahead of when video starts, so they will sync up

Comment: It's possible but not worth it and no guarantees that it would be consistent on connections with high latency.

Comment: If it is possible, how is it accomplished? Connections shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you preload the media or not, synchronization is still a problem.  Even if you had everything in-memory and ready to playback, separate media files can run on two different timebases, and they will drift apart over time.

There used to be a [MediaController interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756580/what-browsers-currently-implement-support-for-the-html5-mediacontroller), which was created to keep separate elements in-sync.  Unfortunately, it was never properly implemented and has been essentially abandoned.

Ideally, you have a single media file with audio and video tracks that are in-sync to begin with.  So, if you can process these server-side, that's best.

You may have some success if you wanted to re-mux the audio/video to MP4 on-the-fly and push it through [Media Source Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API).  This sounds like a pretty large undertaking... I don't know of anything off-the-shelf for this task.

One alternative that would only work if you needed to push the audio back by some fixed amount would be to use the Web Audio API to delay the audio by some number of milliseconds.

Another alternative, if you were to load your audio/video into separate elements, would be to just play them at the same time and use the [`playbackRate` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playbackRate) to drift them into the synchronization that you want.

Comment: Does the playbackRate method really work? I tried it but it didn't speed up the audio at all

Comment: @qwdh It does, yes.  It's what DASH.js uses the catch up to live, for example.  Consider posting a new question with your code where you show how you're setting the `playbackRate`, and drop a link here and I'll take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081031/why-cant-i-set-the-playbackrate-of-this-audio

Comment: Could you please take a look at my code. Thank you so much!